# how to locate the elements which only appear when mouse move to the specific spot in playwright?

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

below is entire part

```
<div class="slc-item" label="2331356104545065455" label_color="#000000" label_name="渡辺もも" item="label_item_wrap">
    <u class="bg"></u>
    <i class="icon-labels il-default"></i>
    <span>渡辺もも</span>    
    <div class="side">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" btn="edit_btn">
            <i class="icon-labels-opt ilo-edit"></i>
        </a>    
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" btn="del_btn">
            <i class="icon-labels-opt ilo-del"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="common-little-pop-wheat" 　undefined="" style="left: -30px; top: -40px; width: 52px; display: none;" id="undefined">
            <i class="arrow" style="left: 58px;"></i>
            <span style="color: #B06B0B; padding-left: 0px">delete</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]
I want click the 'recycle bin icon' to delete,but the icon only appear when mouse move to,and the
the word(in red rectangle) in the right sentence from 'edit' turn to 'delete' .how can I locate the icon without using mouse.move(it is hard to get number of pixels)

Comment: Can't you hover over the previous element?

Comment: @hardkoded you mean the 'edit' icon? I think maybe

Comment: @hardkoded you mean locate the previous element then move some pixels?

Answer (score 1):

```
page.hover(selector[, options])
```

After that you can do

```
page.waitForSlector(selector,{timeout:6000})
```

And then do what you need for your elem.
You can read this:

https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-hover

Comment: but you can't get the 'selector' until u hover there TAT

Comment: You did not understand. You must hover over something first. Lets call it elem 1.
Hover over elem 1, then wait for elem 2 to appear, then do what ever you need with elem 2. Is it more clear now

Comment: In you case,I want elem 2,but elem 2 only appear when I hover to the area where elem 2  will appear),there is not a elem 1 I hover to then elem  2 appear [palmface][palmface][palmface]

Comment: You need to hover over some area.Can that area be located with selector?